# Yes/No Field Default value problem!

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, column, spfield

I have tried following script to set default value of `Yes/No` Field to `Yes` which is by default set to `No` in list Yes/No column, i get false result at last line.

I have tried these values: 1 , $true, "1", Yes and "Yes" at line 1, but nothing works

```
 $item.Fields["My YesNo Field"].DefaultValue = "Yes" //Line 1
    $item.Fields["My YesNo Field"].Update()
    Write-host $item["My YesNo Field"].ToString()
```

Any idea to fix?

Comment: Changing the default value of the field should be at the list setting not the item. Set the default value on the list, then try to update the list item value $item["My YesNo Field"] = "Yes"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the first line to:

```
$item.Fields["My YesNo Field"].DefaultValue = "1"
```

should work.

I can confirm that the following code works in SOM:

```
SPList list = site.Lists["YesNo"];
list.Fields["My YesNo Field"].DefaultValue = "1";
list.Fields["My YesNo Field"].Update();
```